# Генерация паролей на python с условиями

Tags: python, циклы, случайные-числа

Сгенерировать пароль, используя только `random.choice` с условиями:

1. Заглавных букв в пароле должно быть от 20% до 30% от числа символов.
2. Заглавные буквы не должны идти подряд.

Подскажите, как это реализовать без сторонних библиотек.

```
import random

count_symvol = int(input('Введите число не менее 6: '))

spisok = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z')

arr_pass = []
for i in range(0, count_symvol):
    arr_pass.append(random.choice(spisok))
print(arr_pass)
```

Comment: Насколько нужно равномерное оаспределение паролей? Можно всегда в начале чередовать регистры букв, а потом дополнять оставшимися строчными.

Comment: Нельзя для генерации паролей использовать псевдорандом, импортируйте SystemRandom. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если прям совсем нужно учитывать условие и использовать **только** *random.choice*, то могу предложить такой код. Здесь заглавные буквы не идут подряд, а чередуются, что *не нарушает* условие из 2-го пункта.

```
from random import choice


ascii_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
other_strings = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    str_count = int(input())
    if str_count >= 6:
        password = ""
        password += choice(other_strings + ascii_uppercase)
        
        # индекс для цикла, чтобы не уйти в лимит символов верхнего регистра
        if password.isupper():
            upper_index = 1
        else:
            upper_index = 0
        # максимальное число букв в верхнем регистре в районе 20-30%
        str_upper_count = choice(range(int(str_count * 0.2), int(str_count * 0.3) + 1))
        for i in range(str_count-1):
            if password[i].islower() and upper_index < str_upper_count:
                password += choice(ascii_uppercase)
                upper_index += 1
            else:
                password += choice(other_strings)
        print(password)
```

Вывод программы:

```
6
Urwdss

32
FqL9hYiS1lX36yO73eSkGih8wlhd1ma2
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня так получилось. Правда, не смог избавиться от функции sample. Еë можно заменить на перемешивание массива.

```
from random import choice, sample

n = 20
numBig = choice(range(int(n * 0.2), int(n * 0.3) + 1))

ascii_uppercase ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
other = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  
res = ""

def random_combination(iterable, r):
    "Random selection from itertools.combinations(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    indices = sorted(sample(range(n), r))
    return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)


bigPositions = random_combination(range(n - numBig + 1), numBig)

bigCounter = 0
otherCounter = 0
for i in range(n - numBig + 1):
    if bigCounter < numBig and bigPositions[bigCounter] == i:
        res += choice(ascii_uppercase)
        bigCounter += 1
    if len(res) < n:
        res += choice(other)
        
print(res)
```

Comment: спасибо за решение, но препод строгий, надо без сторонних библиотек =(

Comment: @franklin А где вы тут сторонние библиотеки углядели? Кроме `random` ничего нету.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант. Берем делаем две случайные строки через `random.SystemRandom().choice()`: первая — только заглавные, вторая — строчные и цифры. Затем смешиваем через `zip()` и выводим. Если `random.SystemRandom().shuffle()` не разрешается, то можно строку `r.shuffle` закомментить

```
from random import SystemRandom
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase, digits

def gen_password(count: int, upper_perc: int = 30):
    r = SystemRandom()
    upper_count = count * upper_perc // 100
    upper = [r.choice(list(ascii_uppercase)) for _ in range(upper_count)] + [None] * (count - upper_count)
    r.shuffle(upper)
    other = [r.choice(list(ascii_lowercase + digits)) for _ in range(count - upper_count)]
    symb = zip(upper, other) if r.randint(0, 1) else zip(other, upper)
    return ''.join([c for r in symb for c in r if c])

print(gen_password(18))
```

Comment: спасибо за решение, но препод строгий, надо без сторонних библиотек =(

Comment: А какая сторонняя библиотека? Это все компоненты стандартной библиотеки Python.